# Finding pattern occurence count in List with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to find the occurence count of a specific pattern in an integer List with Linq.

I have a list of zeros and ones.

Ex:
List: 000001111100000...
I want to find number of occurences of 011

Comment: Is that a `List<string>` ? If not, how can it be 000001111100000? How do those 0's and 1's exist in an enumerable data structure? An [mcve] can help, if only to show what your input looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your list is in order already (which is a big assumption), you can create a string from the list like so:

```
var numStr = string.Join("", myList);
```

Then from there you can use regular expressions to obtain the count of your pattern:

```
var pattern = "011";
var patternCount = Regex.Matches(numStr, pattern).Count;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is given to you:

```
var list = "000001111100000".Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToList();
var pattern = new[] { 0, 0, 1 };
```

You can find the number of occurrences with:

```
var count = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count - pattern.Length + 1)
    .Count(x => list.Skip(x).Take(pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern));
```